# netgear A6210 driver in ubuntu 19.04

Tags: drivers, compiling, 19.04, netgear

I'm trying to install the driver for the **Netgear A6210 Wifi Adapter** in **Ubuntu 19.04**, but it doesn't work. In **Ubuntu 18.04** it worked fine, though.

This is the process:

```
sammy@sammy-System-Product-Name:~$ cd Documents
sammy@sammy-System-Product-Name:~/Documents$ git clone -b port-to-4.15 https://github.com/kaduke/Netgear-A6210.git
Copy  to 'Netgear-A6210' ...
remote: Enumerating objects: 18, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (18/18), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (12/12), done.
remote: Total 2544 (delta 5), reused 12 (delta 5), pack-reused 2526
receive object: 100% (2544/2544), 6.44 MiB | 7.61 MiB/s, Done.
Resolve differences: 100% (1573/1573), Done.
sammy@sammy-System-Product-Name:~/Documents$ cd Netgear-A6210
sammy@sammy-System-Product-Name:~/Documents/Netgear-A6210$ make
export DBGFLAGS

*** Building driver with debug messages ***

cp -f os/linux/Makefile.6 /home/sammy/Documents/Netgear-A6210/os/linux/Makefile
make -C /lib/modules/5.0.0-25-generic/build DBGFLAGS=-DDBG SUBDIRS=/home/sammy/Documents/Netgear-A6210/os/linux modules
make[1]: Verzeichnis „/usr/src/linux-headers-5.0.0-25-generic“ wird betreten
Makefile:223: ================= WARNING ================
Makefile:224: 'SUBDIRS' will be removed after Linux 5.3
Makefile:225: Please use 'M=' or 'KBUILD_EXTMOD' instead
Makefile:226: ==========================================
  CC [M]  /home/sammy/Documents/Netgear-A6210/os/linux/../../sta/assoc.o
  CC [M]  /home/sammy/Documents/Netgear-A6210/os/linux/../../sta/auth.o
  CC [M]  /home/sammy/Documents/Netgear-A6210/os/linux/../../sta/auth_rsp.o
  CC [M]  /home/sammy/Documents/Netgear-A6210/os/linux/../../sta/sync.o
  CC [M]  /home/sammy/Documents/Netgear-A6210/os/linux/../../sta/sanity.o
  CC [M]  /home/sammy/Documents/Netgear-A6210/os/linux/../../sta/rtmp_data.o
  CC [M]  /home/sammy/Documents/Netgear-A6210/os/linux/../../sta/connect.o
  CC [M]  /home/sammy/Documents/Netgear-A6210/os/linux/../../sta/wpa.o
  CC [M]  /home/sammy/Documents/Netgear-A6210/os/linux/../../sta/sta_cfg.o
  CC [M]  /home/sammy/Documents/Netgear-A6210/os/linux/../../sta/sta.o
  CC [M]  /home/sammy/Documents/Netgear-A6210/os/linux/../../os/linux/sta_ioctl.o
/home/sammy/Documents/Netgear-A6210/os/linux/../../os/linux/sta_ioctl.c: In function ‘rt28xx_sta_ioctl’:
/home/sammy/Documents/Netgear-A6210/os/linux/../../os/linux/sta_ioctl.c:2205:73: error: macro "access_ok" passed 3 arguments, but takes just 2
 f (access_ok(VERIFY_READ, wrqin->u.data.pointer, wrqin->u.data.length) != TRUE)
                                                                      ^

/home/sammy/Documents/Netgear-A6210/os/linux/../../os/linux/sta_ioctl.c:2205:7: error: ‘access_ok’ undeclared (first use in this function)
   if (access_ok(VERIFY_READ, wrqin->u.data.pointer, wrqin->u.data.length) != TRUE)
       ^~~~~~~~~
/home/sammy/Documents/Netgear-A6210/os/linux/../../os/linux/sta_ioctl.c:2205:7: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
make[2]: *** [scripts/Makefile.build:286: /home/sammy/Documents/Netgear-A6210/os/linux/../../os/linux/sta_ioctl.o] Fehler 1
make[1]: *** [Makefile:1606: _module_/home/sammy/Documents/Netgear-A6210/os/linux] Error 2
make[1]: Directory „/usr/src/linux-headers-5.0.0-25-generic“ exit
make: *** [Makefile:64: debug] Error 2
```

Comment: It sounds like this driver was not updated for 5.x series of kernels, those look like Kernel API problems.  You need to reach out to whoever wrote the drivers and have them provide a Kernel 5.x-API capable driver,

Comment: Hello, Thomas Ward, thank you.
for the answer. Fortunately, you no longer need a driver to use the Wifi adapter.